# Configure ModelSim simulation to display text

Tags: verilog, modelsim

Can I make ModelSim simulation to display text (rather than a numeric value) on a signal? I have a couple of state-machine states say,

```
localparam S_IDLE  = 2'b00; 
localparam S_START = 2'b01; 
localparam S_STOP  = 2'b10;
```

Is there a way to display `S_IDLE` for example, on a signal rather than 00? Thanks.

Comment: Check out page 2 here: http://www.uccs.edu/~gtumbush/misc/ModelSim_Hints.pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One thing you can do that is should work across all simulators is to create a signal that holds an ascii string, and then change the radix of that signal to ascii in the simulation window:

```
reg [8*8-1:0] mytextsignal;
always@(state) begin 
    case(state) 
        S_IDLE : mytextsignal = "  S_IDLE";
        S_START: mytextsignal = " S_START";
        S_STOP:  mytextsignal = "  S_STOP";
        default: mytextsignal = " UNKNOWN";
     endcase
 end
```

It should show up as readable text in the waveform viewer.

Comment: Verilog mode has this feature. http://www.veripool.org/wiki/verilog-mode/verilog-mode_veritedium#SEC23

Answer (score 3):

In Modelsim you can add FSM using following steps:

1. use FSM recognition and FSM coverage options (`+acc`, `+cover`) during compile,
2. use the `-fsmdebug` and `-coverage` options on the vsim command line.

Check [ModelSim User's Manual](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/131619-modelsim-user) for more details. Notice that using `View > FSM list` you can check all FSMs detected by ModelSim and add it to a wave.